# IDX20804: Unable to retrieve document from: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration'

Tags: azure, docker, authentication, openid, identity

let's me explain a little.
I have two applications that have the similar appsettings.json, similar Program.cs and similar controller.
I'm trying to hit an endpoint using the token provided by Microsoft.
The only difference between the two applications is: I'm using docker in the application that return this error:

```
 ---> System.IO.IOException: IDX20804: Unable to retrieve document from: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration'.
 ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: No such host is known. (login.microsoftonline.com:443)
 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (11001): No such host is known.
```

And in my other application ( that's not use Docker), I can hit my endpoint

Do you guys think that maybe docker is destroying my Identity in some way?

Answer (score -2):

Sorry man! I don't know.
But run docker logs

Comment: Docker logs show the same error that i put...